# Autocommand for new file of specific filetype

Tags: vim, ftplugin, autocommand

I want to run some vim commands anytime I create a new file of a specific file type, sort of combination of the `BufNewFile` and `FileType` autocommand events.

I have `BufNewFile` autocommands setup in filetype.vim to set the filetype based on the file extension, but I have multiple extensions that all correspond to the same filetype. I'd like to encapsulate the information about which file-extensions correspond to a particular file-type just in this one place, and then have other autocommands run based just on the filetype. However, I can't just use the `FileType` event, because I only want to perform the commands for new files, not when editing existing files.

For instance, in filetype.vim, I have:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.cir setfiletype spice
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.sp setfiletype spice
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.spice setfiletype spice
```

I thought maybe I could add a `BufNewFile` autocommand in the ftplugin file for this filetype, like this:

```
echo "Spice file."
au BufNewFile <buffer> echo "New spice file!"
```

But when I create a new file, e.g., "test.cir", it doesn't run the auto-command. It runs other commands in the ftplugin file (for instance, I get the "Spice file." echo) but not the autocommand.

Alternatively, if there's some way in vimscript that I can tell whether or not a file is new, then I could run the commands directly in the ftplugin, conditioned on whether or not it is new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `BufNewFile` autocommand in the ftplugin file doesn't work, because the event order is wrong. `BufNewFile` triggers `FileType`, not the other way around.

You could split the `au BufRead,BufNewFile` into two separate commands, and set a buffer-local variable `b:isNew` in the first.

But I think it's indeed easiest to check in your ftplugin whether the file is new or not. As this depends on whether the edited file already exists on disk, a simple conditional like this should do:

```
if filereadable(expand('%'))
    " BufRead
else
    " BufNewFile
endif
```

Comment: Works beautifully. However, I found it breaks if I am opening a file over the network with ```vim scp://hostname//pathname```. Even when the file exists on the remote server ```filereadable(expand('%'))``` returns a ```0```

Comment: @Sumit: Yes, functions like `filereadable()` are lower-level; the _netrw_ plugin cannot hook into them, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The following autocommand should be enough to set the filetype based on those three extensions:

```
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.{cir,sp,spice} setlocal filetype=spice
```

Once that autocommand is executed, the `FileType` event is triggered and Vim knows you are editing a file of filetype `spice`: you are free to put whatever fancy options/mappings you want in `~/.vim/ftplugin/spice.vim`:

```
setlocal tabstop=23
nnoremap <buffer> <F7> :echo "Woot!"<CR>
```

Something is not clear, though: do you want to perform a specific action when you create a "spice" buffer or are you unclear about how to define your filetype?

Comment: I understand how to set the filetype based on the file extension, as shown in my `autocommand BufRead,BufNewFile` (though yours nicely shortens this), and I understand how to run commands in the ftplugin, I just need to limit some of those commands to only run the buffer contains a new file. IngoKarkat's answer provides a good example of how to do this.

Comment: OK, that's clearer now. Note that `set filetype` and `setfiletype` are not equivalent. You probably want `set filetype`.